# Where do these OWL and RDF diagrams come from?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl

I found these diagrams on a website a few years ago.  Now I'd like to go back to that website and reread some of the commentary, but I can't member the website address!  I couldn't find anything in my bookmarks, and I printed the diagrams without any headers or footers.

I think it may have been a German or Scandinavian university, but I also remember reading something about industrial applications, like inventory for off-shore oil well or something like that.

Do you recognize them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/EasierRDF/issues/6#issuecomment-449000962? AFAIK, the author is an ISO 15926 evangelist.

Comment: That's a great start, but my original source wasn't GitHub.  I'll attach another image I from the same site. Did you use Google reverse image search?  I tried that and just got a bunch of children's drawings!

Comment: @StanislavKralin yeah, ISO 15926 was a good lead. I think my figures may have come from http://www.infowebml.ws.  Visiting any page from that domain in Chrome or Firefox is giving me this error now:  "This Account has been suspended."

Comment: i have them also; the source **was** https://www.infowebml.ws/rdf-owl/graphical-representations.htm#Statement The page title was: Graphical Representations of RDF/RDFS/OWL entity types. I have the original, but not additional provenance. There actually are 6 images on the source page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I think are the originals through https://tineye.com/

[The source web page](http://www.infowebml.ws/website/graphical-representations.htm) is no longer online, but it was [captured by the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20071011172027/http://www.infowebml.ws/website/graphical-representations.htm).

Comment: That's the best reverse image search I've seen. Thanks for pointing it out!